# Antiproton production efficiency

Tags: antimatter, pair-production

according to Fermilab articles and a few physics books at my library, for every million collisions of protons accelerated on a target, only 1 to 30 antiprotons are created.

Why is the efficiency so low? I mean, I know it's very expensive to accelerate protons on the target, but for one collision, there is a chance out of up to a million to get an antiproton...

Is it because there is empty space between the atoms in the target?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one goes to the atomic and particle level, one has to use quantum mechanics and special relativity to make sense of the data and the efficiencies.

In quantum mechanics there is a calculable  probability for producing a proton-antiproton pair whenever in particle scattering there exists enough energy, but this probability is small. Antiporotns have to come from pair creation because of baryon number conservation ( another quantum mechanical rule). Thus the crossection of producing antiprotons  is energy dependent and gets higher with energy but it is still much smaller than the probability of generating other particles. See [figure 5 here](https://indico.nucleares.unam.mx/event/4/session/8/contribution/785/material/paper/0.pdf) .